# Creating a new UI for a token

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, wallets, metamask, cryptokitties

Is it possible to create an user interface for a new token created with ERC20 and metaMask? If yes, how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an UI with those tools. Metamask offers only the interface between blockchain and JavaScript but you need other tools to actually create an UI around the concept. So the flow goes something like this:

UI -> JavaScript -> Metamask (web3js) -> some node -> blockchain

There are many guides for this, one comprehensive one is: https://medium.com/@merunasgrincalaitis/the-ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-and-deploy-a-fully-descentralized-dapp-in-ethereum-18f0cf6d7e0e